Can instances generated using "Geometry Node Instances" setting in the gltf exporter be differentiated in any way?
The experimental "Geometry Node Instances" setting in the gltf exporter is extremely useful for my use-case: I'm using a "room generator" geometry node which outputs the inside and the outside walls separately (so they can be culled separately by the game engine).
Is there any way at to differentiate these instances once they are exported? All separate instances are simply named "GN Instance" and I couldn't find a way to rename them. I found the source code for the feature and the "GN Instance" name is hard-coded. I probably could use materials to differentiate between instances, but I don't want to lose the ability to use materials for their visuals. So I'm wondering if there's any way at all

For Blender 4.4, there's a simple edit that can be done to add a bit more info the the GN Instances:

Navigate to the /scripts/addons_core/io_scene_gltf2/blender/exp/ folder and open the nodes.py file.

Alter the _gather_name function to receive an extra parameter, and use that parameter to get the name of the original object:
def __gather_name(blender_object, export_settings, vnode):

    new_name = "GN Instance"

    if vnode.parent_uuid:
        if export_settings['vtree'].nodes[vnode.parent_uuid].blender_object:
            new_name = "%s_%s" % (new_name, export_settings['vtree'].nodes[vnode.parent_uuid].blender_object.name)

    new_name = blender_object.name if blender_object else new_name


Change the only _gather_name call, from:
__gather_name(blender_object, export_settings)
to __gather_name(blender_object, export_settings, vnode)

Done! GN Instances will now also include their original names.


